# Why do Biter Spawners appear inside my base in Factorio?

Tags: factorio

I was playing a map with fixed max width to 400 and unlimited height. I placed boundary walls north and south of my base. My base was not that big since I was playing single player all the time.

When my tech reached Rocket Silo construction, a biter base appeared inside the boundary of my base. Though it was a little away from factory but it was within my boundary region.

I heard that biters don't spawn where a player has some factory or any kind of infrastructure. So why is it that there was a spawner inside my base not far from my rocket silo?

Comment: Yes I scouted the area myself. There was no base initially or as I expanded. All the area where I wanted to expand was clean. But later in the game I started getting attacked despite being defended by turrets. After noticing the whole map again I found 1 enemy base and then later another enemy base, not far away from my factory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Biters will expand their bases (something that I just learned).  The [Enemies Wiki page](https://wiki.factorio.com/Enemies#Spawners) states:

> Every 4-60 minutes, a group of 5-20 biters will leave their base to create a new base. This group will search for a suitable spot that's at least 3 chunks and at most 7 chunks away from existing biter bases. Once they have found a suitable spot the group of biters dies and forms a new base. This new base will first be very small (about one spawner and a few worms) but will get some additional spawners within a small area as time passes.

You said you have walls guarding the north and south portion of your base, but is it possible that any aliens could have got by it in any way? Are your walls completely impervious with no gaps?  I would say that somewhere biters were able to get pass your barrier and made a base within yours.  It's probably a very rare chance of happening, but it can happen.  You will have to check your walls and make sure there is no way for biters to get by it. I would also consider increasing the amount of defenses you have so that no future biters can make their way in.

Keep in mind that if you have your wall connect to a body of water, make sure that the wall can no longer be placed any further.  You may think that the water is close enough to your wall to the point where nothing can get pass, but if you can walk around the wall by walking into the water some, then it's not fully connected to the body of water.

**Edit:**  [Version 16.0](https://wiki.factorio.com/Version_history/0.16.0) changed how the transition of terrain to water works.  You can no longer build objects on these transition tiles (or walk on these tiles), meaning if you build your walls right up to the water, you should be fine.

> Transition from terrain to water is no longer buildable, meaning entities can no longer be built partially on the water.

Comment: Oh man! Thanks for reminding. I just checked and there was a gap in my boundary wall which was 'APPARENTLY' attached to water. I missed one block of wall. Well actually, 2 blocks of wall since I build 2 layers wall. Thanks mate, that explains.